# Draw curve does not cross a node

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am in need of help to make the following graph:

[image]

But I can't bend the edge without going over the vertex.

```
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 0.75]
            \tikzstyle{every state}=[fill opacity=0.5,text opacity=1,semithick,minimum size=10pt]
            \tikzset{roundnode/.style={thick, draw = black, fill = white, outer sep = 1.5, circle, minimum size = 10pt, scale = 0.75}}
            
            \node[roundnode = black] (1) at (30, 2.01){1};
            \node[roundnode = black] (2) at (31.91, 0.62){2};
            \node[roundnode = black] (3) at (31.18, -1.63){3};
            \node[roundnode = black] (4) at (28.82, -1.63){4};
            \node[roundnode = black] (5) at (28.09, 0.62){5};
            
            \draw
            (1) edge[-,thick]   (2)
            (2) edge[-,thick]   (3)
            (3) edge[-,thick]   (4)
            (4) edge[-,thick]   (5)
            (5) edge[-,thick]   (1)
            %(3) edge[-,thick]   (4)
           
        \end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Please, provide a minimal working example https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/231952

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to use `controls`:

[image: the graph]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=20]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 0.75]
        \tikzstyle{every state}=[fill opacity=0.5,text opacity=1,semithick,minimum size=10pt]
        \tikzset{roundnode/.style={thick, draw = black, fill = white, outer sep = 1.5, circle, minimum size = 10pt, scale = 0.75}}
        
        \node[roundnode = black] (1) at (30, 2.01){1};
        \node[roundnode = black] (2) at (31.91, 0.62){2};
        \node[roundnode = black] (3) at (31.18, -1.63){3};
        \node[roundnode = black] (4) at (28.82, -1.63){4};
        \node[roundnode = black] (5) at (28.09, 0.62){5};
            
        \draw
        (1) edge[-,thick]   (2)
        (2) edge[-,thick]   (3)
        (3) edge[-,thick]   (4)
        (4) edge[-,thick]   (5)
        (5) edge[-,thick]   (1)
        (3) edge[-,thick]   (4);
            
        \draw (1) edge[-,thick] (4);
        \draw (1) edge[-,thick] (3);
        \draw[thick] (5) .. controls ($(1) + (0, 1.5)$) .. (2);
        \draw[thick] (4) .. controls ($(3) + (0.8, -1)$) .. (2);
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need enough bend.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[enough bend/.style={looseness=2,bend left=80}] foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \y using {162-72*\x}] in {1,...,5}
  {(\y:2) node[circle,fill,inner sep=1.5pt,label=\y:{$\x$}](\x){}
  \ifnum\x>1
   edge (1) edge (\the\numexpr\x-1)
  \fi}
  (5) to[enough bend] (2)
  (2) to[enough bend] (4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image: edge bend]

Use either `[out=90,in=90]` to specify out angle and in angle or `[bend right=<val>]`, then `looseness` to allow your path to be more or less away from your nodes.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[thick,scale = 0.75]
            \tikzstyle{every state}=[fill opacity=0.5,text opacity=1,semithick,minimum size=10pt]
            \tikzset{roundnode/.style={thick, draw = black, fill = white, outer sep = 1.5, circle, minimum size = 10pt, scale = 0.75}}
            
            \foreach \i in {1,...,5}
                \node[roundnode] (\i) at (162-72*\i:3){\i};
            
            \draw
            (1) edge   (2)
            (2) edge   (3)
            (3) edge   (4)
            (4) edge   (5)
            (5) edge   (1)
            (3) edge   (1)
            (4) edge   (1)
            (4) to[bend right=80,looseness=2] (2)
            (5) edge[out=90,in=90,looseness=2]   (2);
           
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```